# Missing Keyword in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SELECT INTO Statement - Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

The query below is a simplified version of the PL/SQL I am trying to run that just shows the general structure. In short, I am trying to extract information from `SPECIAL_TABLE` into the variables `c, d`.

```
DECLARE
  c NUMBER;
  d NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR all_tab IN
  (SELECT * FROM all_tables)
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT a, d INTO c, d
      FROM ' || :name || '.SPECIAL_TABLE WHERE name = '''
      :name || ''' AND table_name = ''' || all_tab.table_name || ''';

    ...

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR OCCURRED');
    END;
END;
```

The above query does not work (by above query I mean the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`), and Oracle states `905 missing keyword`. Following the flow [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm) is followed as far as I can tell. Note that the `'''` is so that I can escape a single `'` for the `SELECT` statement, and then finish off the whole string all together. What is strange, is that I can follow the below code and run into no errors:

```
DECLARE
  c NUMBER;
  d NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR all_tab IN
  (SELECT * FROM all_tables)
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM ' || :name || '.SPECIAL_TABLE WHERE name = '''
      :name || ''' AND table_name = ''' || all_tab.table_name || ''' INTO c;

    ...

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR OCCURRED');
    END;
END;
```

The only thing that changes is that I am using `MAX(...)`, and seemingly no longer following the specified syntax in the above hyperlink. I'm not sure about the syntax part and why exactly this works, and `MAX(...)` would ensure only returning a single row. It seems like this would be the source of the problem, but when I perform the `SELECT` query by itself it only returns a *single row* with the two columns specified. The primary key for the table is `PRIMARY KEY (a, b)` so it shouldn't return more than one row regardless.

What am I missing here and how can I get my initial statement to work to assign the result of a query into multiple variables in Oracle 11g?

Comment: In execute immediate query, caluse INTO is forbidden. It can only appear after string: EX IM 'SELECT a,d FROM...' INTO c ,b

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The link you provided is for the `SELECT INTO` statement. When selecting into variables using [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm) you have to play by EXECUTE IMMEDIATE's rules.

So instead of this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT x FROM myTable INTO y';
                                         ^ Incorrect: INTO is inside the string
```

You have to do this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT x FROM myTable' INTO y;
                                          ^ Correct: INTO is an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE keyword
```

Your query would go something like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT a, d '
  || 'FROM ' || :name || '.SPECIAL_TABLE '
  || 'WHERE name = ''' || :name || ''' AND table_name = ''' || all_tab.table_name || ''''
INTO c, d;
```